# The $n\times n$ matrix $(a_{ij})$ with $\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij} = 1$ has an eigenvalue 1.

Tags: linear-algebra

**The Problem**

Let $A = (a_{ij})$ be an $n\times n$ matrix such that 
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} = 1
$$
for all $i = 1,2,\dots,n$. Show that $A$ has an eigenvalue $1$.

I tried to figure out from $A - \lambda I v = \mathbf{0}$ but now I'm stuck.

Comment: Do it directly. Write down a vector $v\neq 0$ with $Av = v$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $v = (1,1,\ldots, 1)$. What is $A(v)$?

Answer (score 0):

Although the solutions by Prahlad and Daniel are optimal, there is another (more complicated) way to do it starting from julypraise's initial attempt. To show that the characteristic polynomial $\det(t I_n - A)$ has a root at $t = 1$, we have to show that $I_n - A$ has determinant zero. The sum of the entries of each row of $I_n - A$ is zero since the sum of the entries of each row of $A$ is $1$. In other words, the sum of the column vectors is the zero vector, i.e., the column vector space is contained in the space of vectors $(v_1, \ldots, v_n): v_1 + \ldots + v_n$. This space has dimension $n-1$, less than full dimension $n$. Since this implies there is a linear dependency between the column vectors, it must be that the matrix $I_n - A$ has determinant zero.